# Counting the number of continuous alphabets in string, and then sort based on their frequency

Tags: python, string, sorting, alphabetical

I'm trying to count the amount of times each letter repeats in a string, and then sort this. For example, say my string is as:

```
AADDADCBBB
```

I want to create a function to return the amount of times in a row each letter repeats; in this case, we would get:

```
"A: 2, D: 2, A: 1, D: 1, C: 1, B: 3"
```

Then, I want to be able to sort this based on the:

- maximum frequency, *and*
- in alphabetical order

Expected result is:

```
"B: 3, A: 2, D: 2, A: 1, C: 1, D: 1"
```

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: Looks like you identified the steps, now simply implement them.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to do that, which is why I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to achieve this as:

```
from itertools import groupby
my_str = 'AADDADCBBB'

tup = [(i, len(list(l))) for i, l in groupby(my_str)]
```

where `tup` is the list of tuple holding the *alphabet* and it's *count* as:

```
[('A', 2), ('D', 2), ('A', 1), ('D', 1), ('C', 1), ('B', 3)]
```

Now, to sort this tuple based on the count of alphabets and then based on the lexicographical precedence, you can use [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) with key as `lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])`.

Here, `-[1]` will sort the tuple based on the decreasing order of value of element at `1`st index. If this value is same for multiple tuple, secondary sorting will be done on `x[0]`. It will sort based on the element present at `0`th index in ascending order.

For example:

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted_tup = sorted(tup, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
```

where `sorted_tup` will hold the value:

```
[('B', 3), ('A', 2), ('D', 2), ('A', 1), ('C', 1), ('D', 1)]
```